# agent cannot connect to server

Tags: azure, devops, agent

## Connect with Pat

```
Enter server URL > https://xxx
Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT) > 
Enter personal access token > ****************************************************
An error occurred while sending the request.
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
```

## Connect using HTTPS

```
Enter server URL > http://xxxx
Enter authentication type (press enter for Negotiate) > 
Enter user name > xxx
Enter password > *******
An error occurred while sending the request.
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
```

I already have an agent. I want to add another one.

My account has admin permission

Comment: It's my fault. I wrote the wrong URL